# Jquery - find element after image upload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using [html5Uploader](http://www.igloolab.com/jquery-html5-uploader/) to upload images and everything is working fine. The part I am interested is the following:

After images are uploaded, new elements are being added to the DOM (**img** tag is added for the preview, among others). 
After this element is created, I need to be able to attach an on click event. How can I do this (check when this element appears)?

**EDIT:**

This is the code that is producing preview:

```
$(function()
    {var fileTemplate="<div id=\"{{id}}\">";
    fileTemplate+="<div class=\"preview\"></div>";
    fileTemplate+="<div class=\"filename\">{{filename}}</div>";
    fileTemplate+="</div>";
    function slugify(text)
    {
        text=text.replace(/[^-a-zA-Z0-9,&\s]+/ig,'');
        text=text.replace(/-/gi,"_");text=text.replace(/\s/gi,"-");
        return text;
    }
$("#dropbox").html5Uploader({
    postUrl: "<?php echo base_url() ?>admin/image_upload",
onClientLoadStart:function(e,file)
    {var upload=$("#upload");
    if(upload.is(":hidden"))
        {upload.show();}
upload.append(fileTemplate.replace(/{{id}}/g,slugify(file.name)).replace(/{{filename}}/g,file.name));},
onClientLoad:function(e,file)
{$("#"+slugify(file.name)).find(".preview").append("<img class=img_upload title=\"" + file.name + "\" src=\""+e.target.result+"\" alt=\"\">");},
onServerLoad:function(e,file)
        {}
    });
```

And this is the part where I need try to attach **on click** event:

```
$('.preview').on('click', '.img_upload', function(){
var _val = textarea.val(),
img_src = '<img src="<?php echo IMG ?>vesti/' + $(this).attr('title') + '" />';
console.log(img_src);
textarea.val( _val + img_src );
});
```

});

Comment: doesnt $('img').on("click",function(){}); work?

Comment: Yes, but I need to to attach more function to it, and at the moment I can attach only one function per click. I am trying some different approaches in order to meet the requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the code that attaches the image to the preview element

```
$("#" + slugify(file.name) ).find(".preview")
    .append( 
        $("<img class=img_upload title=\"" +
        file.name +
        "\" src=\"" + e.target.result + 
        "\" alt=\"\">").on("click", function( ) { // do stuff })
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of silly to try and check when the element appears. Something is making the element appear! Attach the handler then, or at least keep track of the element so you can attach whatever later.

How are you creating your preview nodes?